# how to reach into PHP nested arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, nested

I've a nested array whose print_r looks like this-

```
Array
(
    [keyId] => Array
        (
            [hostname] => 192.168.1.127
            [results] => Array
                (
                    [1] => false
                    [2] => false
                    [3] => false
                )

            [sessionIDs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ed9f79e4-2640-4089-ba0e-79bec15cb25b
                )

        )
```

I would like to process(print key and value) of the "results" array. How do I do this?

I am trying to use array_keys function to first get all the keys and if key name is "results", process the array. But problem is array_keys is not reaching into the "results"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($array['keyId']['results'] as $k => $v) {
    // use $k and $v
}
```

Answer (score 3):

php's [foreach](http://in.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop is what you need.

```
foreach($arr['keyId']['results'] as $key => $value) {
   //$key contains key and $value contains values.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The array you want is `$array['keyID']['results']`.  From there you access the values with `$array['keyID']['results'][1]`, `$array['keyID']['results'][2]`, `$array['keyID']['results'][3]`

To loop through it just do this:

```
foreach($array['keyId']['results'] as $key => $value) {
   echo $key . ' ' . $value;
}
```

or

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; i++)
{
    echo $i . ' ' . $array['keyID']['results'][i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to navigate through the array is this.

```
//Assuming, your main array is $array
foreach($array as $value) { //iterate over each item

   if(isset($value['results']) && count($value['results'])) { 
   // ^ check if results is present

       //Now that we know results exists, lets use foreach loop again to get the values
       foreach($value['result'] as $k => $v) {
           //The boolean values are now accessible with $v
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with SO, today? Downvotes are being fired on me. Without Comments.

Comment: @Jon, I meant SO users, I am afraid somebody hates me.

Comment: That's absurd. You should be more "afraid" that your answers need improvement: for example, this one is not practical at all and there is also no explanation at all. To me it looks like a bad idea *and* the OP may have difficult time adapting to other code on top of that.

Comment: @Jon, My answer has more explanation than yours does.

Comment: ...which, along with the fact that we are talking about ultra beginner level PHP syntax, is why I made mine community wiki. It would have been a comment instead if I didn't need the space to format the code. In any case, it might serve *you* better to look into how *your* answers can be improved.

Comment: @Jon, I mean no disrespect, but I do not care about what you think. I have flagged this for moderation attention, and they will provide me with correct info.

Comment: Not *agreeing* with what people think is fine. Not *caring* about it is simply stupid. No disrespect.

Comment: @Jon, I do care, thats why I am trying, but I dont know How I could judge OP as beginner and give a solution based on that. You have seen my answer, how would you improve it.

Comment: Ibrahim's answer is probably the best one here; yours does not even say *how* to access one of the boolean values. The OP is obviously a newbie since they are getting tripped up on simple *syntax*; it's certain that they cannot understand how to use your answer as it stands.

Comment: Well, the `count` does nothing because `foreach` will iterate over an empty array zero times anyway, so remove that; the outer foreach loop is wasteful and can also result in buggy behavior (what if there is another element with a subkey "results"? did you ask the OP about it?) so remove that too; which basically leaves you with the same as Ibrahim. :)

Comment: @Jon, Yeah I should have asked about multiple items. But about the count, if there is no item it will return 0, which is make the condition to evaluate false hence it will not go into the statement. Or, Am I wrong?

Comment: The point is that you don't care if it goes into the loop, because the loop will run zero times.

Comment: @Jon, Please explain to me, how will the loop be executed, if the condition will evaluate to `false`.

Comment: Sorry, but I just don't have the time for this.